# Why does getting Cycles devices fail with Blender 3.0?

Tags: python

This used to work perfectly with 2.92 but now fails with 3.0

```
preferences = bpy.context.preferences
cycles_preferences = preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences
cuda_devices, opencl_devices = cycles_preferences.get_devices()
```

with message `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object`

Is there some change I can't find the docs to?

Answer (score 4):

Because `cycles_preferences.get_devices()` is returning `None`.  You want  `cycles_preferences.devices` instead.  But that may fail with a different error if you have more than two entries in `devices`.  On my system, that's currently returning 3 devices.

If you try `get_devices` and a <kbd>Tab</kbd> for completion in the Python console you get this:

```
>>> cycles_preferences.get_devices(
get_devices(self, compute_device_type='')
# Deprecated: use refresh_devices instead.
```

But further investigation says that just updates the device list.  So your code should probably be

```py
preferences = bpy.context.preferences
cycles_preferences = preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences
cycles_preferences.refresh_devices()
cuda_devices = cycles_preferences.devices[0]
opencl_devices = cycles_preferences.devices[1]
```